# Read file into R keeping end of lines

Tags: r

Probably a simple question and I have looked at the many options in `scan` but havent got what I want yet.

A simple example would be

```
require(httr)
example <- content(GET("http://www.r-project.org"), as = 'text')
write(example, 'text.txt')
input <- readLines('text.txt')

> example
[1] "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>The R Project for Statistical Computing</title>\n<link rel=\"icon\" href=\"favicon.ico\" type=\"image/x-icon\">\n<link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"favicon.ico\" type=\"image/x-icon\">\n<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"R.css\">\n</head>\n\n<FRAMESET cols=\"1*, 4*\" border=0>\n<FRAMESET rows=\"120, 1*\">\n<FRAME src=\"logo.html\" name=\"logo\" frameborder=0>\n<FRAME src=\"navbar.html\" name=\"contents\" frameborder=0>\n</FRAMESET>\n<FRAME src=\"main.shtml\" name=\"banner\" frameborder=0>\n<noframes>\n<h1>The R Project for Statistical Computing</h1>\n\nYour browser seems not to support frames,\nhere is the <A href=\"navbar.html\">contents page</A> of the R Project's\nwebsite.\n</noframes>\n</FRAMESET>\n\n\n\n"

input
 [1] "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">"       
 [2] "<html>"                                                                  
 [3] "<head>"                                                                  
 [4] "<title>The R Project for Statistical Computing</title>"                  
 [5] "<link rel=\"icon\" href=\"favicon.ico\" type=\"image/x-icon\">"          
 [6] "<link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"favicon.ico\" type=\"image/x-icon\">" 
 [7] "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"R.css\">"              
 [8] "</head>"                                                                 
 [9] ""                                                                        
[10] "<FRAMESET cols=\"1*, 4*\" border=0>"                                     
[11] "<FRAMESET rows=\"120, 1*\">"                                             
[12] "<FRAME src=\"logo.html\" name=\"logo\" frameborder=0>"                   
[13] "<FRAME src=\"navbar.html\" name=\"contents\" frameborder=0>"             
[14] "</FRAMESET>"                                                             
[15] "<FRAME src=\"main.shtml\" name=\"banner\" frameborder=0>"                
[16] "<noframes>"                                                              
[17] "<h1>The R Project for Statistical Computing</h1>"                        
[18] ""                                                                        
[19] "Your browser seems not to support frames,"                               
[20] "here is the <A href=\"navbar.html\">contents page</A> of the R Project's"
[21] "website."                                                                
[22] "</noframes>"                                                             
[23] "</FRAMESET>"                                                             
[24] ""                                                                        
[25] ""                                                                        
[26] ""                                                                        
[27] ""
```

the motivation for this is that I want to store various files in Postgresql and I am passing them in in the format given by `example` as opposed to `input`. Apologies if I havent explained very well.

@Hong Ooi gave a nice answer using readChar. I have encoding issues so have had to wrap

```
iconv(readChar(file, nchars=file.info(file)["size"], TRUE), from = "latin1", to = "UTF-8")
```

to stop the database complaining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want all those strings concatenated into a single string:

```
paste(input, collapse="\n")
```

---

Alternatively, if you're reading from a file and want to avoid splitting the input into bits and putting them back together:

```
f <- readChar(file, nchars=file.info(file)["size"], TRUE)
```

Comment: Yes this is one solution. I am looking for a way to read the "raw" file in if you like.

Comment: I don't get it. You already have `example`, which is the source data in one big string. In fact, all that my answer does is recreate `example` from `input`. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I dont have the source data. I have the files. I want to read them in warts and all as it were.

Comment: Yes this is more like what I want. I have a vague recollection that back in the day `scan` used to work like this?

Comment: Not that I recall. `scan` has always been intended for (semi-)structured data, ie stuff that can be parsed into a set of distinct values.